# The GANs gaussian simulator doesn't converge.

Tags: mxnet

I try to reimplement the Gaussian simulator described in the GANs paper with mxnet.

But there are two problems in my [code](https://github.com/HuitingLiu/mxnet_demo/blob/master/gans.py).

First, the model doesn't converge very well, even after I try to set a learning rate scheduler.

[This is how it looks like after about 500 epochs and the accuracy is bouncing around 0.5 ~ 0.6.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikAlh.png)

Second, I don't know how to draw the output of the discriminative model. The current curve doesn't look like the one described in the paper.

Could anyone please offer any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved the two problems by myself. Now the code in the Github link should be correct.